# iphoto-like thumbnail view with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphoto

I'd like to create an iphoto-like album thumbnail viewer, just with words, not photos.
For example, when you mouseover over a div box, the div box text changes as you incrementally move right with your mouse.

Does anyone have an idea about how to begin developing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I google for "javascript text lens" and found [this](http://labs.bitmeister.jp/moamoa/demo.html) . HTH.